# How to specify msg source and destination in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

In TicToc tutorial 13, the message destination is random. How can I specify the destination of the message? say I want it to get to `tic[5]` arriving from `tic[0]`. Then create another message with different source and destination e.g. from `tic[3]` to `tic[2]`.
Also the paths are randomly selected between the nodes in this tutorial, so how can I modify this so the message can get to its destination using shortest path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set any values as source and destination of a message in `TicToc13`, for example:

```
TicTocMsg13 *msg = new TicTocMsg13("Test message");
msg->setSource(0);
msg->setDestination(5);
```

According second part of the question:
TicToc examples were prepared to show and learn how to use `OMNeT++` and how to control behavior of model using C++. They do not reflect real systems. Therefore "routing" in TicToc13 is very simple (i.e. random). Choosing shortest path for routing requires more sophisticated routing protocol that has some knowledge about topology. Preparing such protocol for TicToc model could be possible but many additional things will be necessary (i.e. routing table, control messages, a way to configure/share routing information etc.). What is more all these issues have been already resolved for IP protocols.